# Change the page orientation in middle of doc

Tags: docx4j

I need to set landscape to some pages of a document. I tried this code:

```
    SectPr sectionLandscape = objectFactory.createSectPr();

String rsidR = sectionLandscape.getRsidR();     

SectPr sectionPortrait = objectFactory.createSectPr();
sectionPortrait.setRsidR(rsidR);
sectionPortrait.setRsidSect(rsidR);    

PgSz landscape = new PgSz();
landscape.setOrient(STPageOrientation.LANDSCAPE);
landscape.setH(BigInteger.valueOf(11906));
landscape.setW(BigInteger.valueOf(16383));       

sectionLandscape.setPgSz(landscape);

mdp.addObject(sectionLandscape);
```

It creates this xml code:

```
<w:sectPr>
    <w:pgSz w:w="16383" w:orient="landscape" w:h="11906"/>
</w:sectPr>
```

And after of the Section tag have the text and the table that i need inside landscape page. With Word 2007/2010 i only see the portrait page and in editing mode of the page I can see the page selected as landscape.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHuGB.png

Comment: No need for the rsId stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sectPr should be in a w:p/w:pPr **after** the content which it is to appear in landscape orientation.

You need sectPr specifying portrait before that content.

Comment: Thanks! It works, I tested with this code and works:


    SectPr sectionLandscape = objectFactory.createSectPr();
  
    PgSz landscape = new PgSz();
    landscape.setOrient(STPageOrientation.LANDSCAPE);
    landscape.setH(BigInteger.valueOf(11906));
    landscape.setW(BigInteger.valueOf(16383));
     
    sectionLandscape.setPgSz(landscape);     
    
    org.docx4j.wml.P p = objectFactory.createP();
  
    PPr createPPr = objectFactory.createPPr();
    createPPr.setSectPr(sectionLandscape);
  
    p.setPPr(createPPr);
     
    mdp.addObject(p);